# sslstream throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, ssl

I'm using .net's SslStream class to handle Http traffic. Problem I'm facing is that if the ssl handshake fails for whatever reason .net will throw an exception, which leaves me vulnerable to dos attacks since .net exceptions are rather slow and shouldn't be used in normal program flow.

Are there alternatives to using SslStream or is there a way to make the SslStream handle failures 'silently' (without exceptions)? What would you suggest?

Here's the code (exceptions may be thrown on the 'AuthenticateAsServer' call):

```
        public void Init(Socket s, bool isSSL)
    {
        m_s = s;
        this.isSSL = isSSL;
        stream = new NetworkStream(s);
        if (isSSL)
        {
            SslStream sslstrm = new SslStream(stream);
            stream = sslstrm;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                sslstrm.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate,
    false, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

        }

    }
```

Comment: You can't exactly stop a code you didn't write from throwing exceptions at all. To start, is there a reason you can't use try catch blocks for exception handling?

Comment: And even if you could, how would you like it to communicate an error (a fatal one at that) to you if not by throwing an exception? In any case, I don't see how avoiding an exception here would make this code any more resistant to a DOS attack.

Comment: Surely a 'return false' would be more efficient than throwing/handling the exception(s).

Comment: The question of using exceptions vs. return values is a whole other discussion, but the short of it is that in most cases, exceptions are considered a vastly better design for error handling that far outweighs the performance overhead. In cases where frequent failures are legitimately expected, then yes, the API would be designed to use return values rather than throw exceptions. In some cases, they might do both, such as with `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.TryParse`.

Comment: Regardless, it's a moot point here because even if you could somehow keep the exception from being thrown at runtime, it would be impossible (without the source) to change the return type of the `AuthenticateAsServer` method to boolean, much less change the code in the method to return a "success" flag that way.

Comment: I suggest that you handle the handshake failures and other exceptions in the normal way here, and focus on better ways to defend the app/service from DOS attacks. If your firewall or other traditional methods aren't sufficient and you feel you need to build defenses into the code, then you'll have to put some time into engineering that. I'm not qualified to even attempt something like that, but at the very least, you'd probably need to come up with some rate-limiting logic at a higher level than this method.

Comment: Would (temporarily) blocking ips that throw ssl exceptions qualify as 'rate-limiting-logic'? I'm currently making an attempt to copy the sources from mono but as you can imagine i'm hitting a lot of brick walls...

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a non-trivial task. And yes, that is conceptually what I mean by rate-limiting, but a proper production-ready implementation is also a non-trivial task. Perhaps you do, but I don't have the expertise to do that or probably even advise you much further (though feel free to ask).